# Do I need to invite testers pro-actively to a closed test in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play

For an Android app test with a closed testing track, the documentation suggests that it is necessary to list all testers who will have access to a closed test:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?visit_id=637733572515958404-1166172922&rd=1#zippy=

You also get a shareable link though. When people who are not in your email list click this link, will they be able to join the closed test or not?

Answer (score 3):

No, they will not. You will have to add all the different email addresses of these users to the closed testing group. Once they are added to the list, they will have an option to join the beta when navigating to the app in the Play Store (or using your link). The link is exactly the same for users in your closed testing track ánd outside your testing track.